# On sufficient conditions for planar convex regions to be circular disks.

Tags: convex-geometry, discrete-geometry

1. If C is a planar convex region and there is a point P on its boundary such that the perpendicular bisectors of all chords to C starting at P are concurrent, then, can we assert that C is necessarily a circular disk?
2. If C is a planar convex region and if there is a real number a such that perpendicular bisectors of all chords of C with length a are concurrent, then, can we assert that C is a circular disk?

Comment: The first part is trivial, as all boundary points are equidistant from the concurrency point.

Comment: Yes. Thanks very much for pointing this out!